# The Result is not coming in correct format in Java code

Tags: java, string, algorithm, stringbuilder, system.out

Here in I want the Stringbuilder to append the result of each calculation.
But its not coming in the correct format.

In the code I am trying to find all the comman factors of two numbers and getting the kth value. But my result is not coming in the expected format.

```
Expected Correct Output
4
1
No candy today
```

And what I am getting is this :-

```
4

4
1

4
1

No candy today
```

I need to use StringBuilder so as to fast process the output. Instead of calling the System.out each time I need to call it only once.

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int D = scan.nextInt();
        int x = 0, y = 0, k = 0;
        List<Integer> commonDivisor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(D-->0){
            commonDivisor.clear();
            x = scan.nextInt();
            y = scan.nextInt();
            k = scan.nextInt();
            k = k - 1;

            commonDivisor = getCommonDivisor(x, y);
            Collections.reverse(commonDivisor);
            if(k >= (commonDivisor.size())){
              sb.append("\nNo candy today");
            }else if(k <= (commonDivisor.size() - 1)){
                 sb.append(commonDivisor.get(k) + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> getCommonDivisor(int num1, int num2) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int min = minimum(num1, num2);

    for(int i = 1; i <= min / 2; i++) { 
        if (num1 % i == 0 && num2 % i == 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    if (num1 % min == 0 && num2 % min == 0) {
        list.add(min);
    }

    return list;
  }

  public static int minimum(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 <= num2 ? num1 : num2;
  }

}
```

Comment: write `System.out.println(sb);` after `while loop` and try...

Comment: Thanks write it as answer I will accept.

Comment: Note that for trivial concatenation like this it doesn't really matter. Are you experiencing actual performance issues?

Comment: Yes. I am experiencing and even after using StringBuider its not getting resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the string builder inside every loop iteration, so you print all the steps. Since you want to avoid printing inside the loop and instead build a string that you print at the very end you should move the print statement outside of the loop:

```
while(D-->0){
    commonDivisor.clear();
    x = scan.nextInt();
    y = scan.nextInt();
    k = scan.nextInt();
    k = k - 1;

    commonDivisor = getCommonDivisor(x, y);
    Collections.reverse(commonDivisor);
    if (k >= commonDivisor.size()) {
       sb.append("\nNo candy today");
    } else if (k <= (commonDivisor.size() - 1)){
       sb.append(commonDivisor.get(k) + "\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either clear your stringBuilder once its done for a test case or you should print after processing all the test cases. You already hold that and print it in while loop after every test case. So two ways to resolve the issue:

```
}//while loop ends
System.out.println(sb);//this is what i would prefer
```

Or

```
while(D-->0){
     sb = new StringBuilder();
     ...
```

Comment: How to initialize a StringBuilder.

Comment: see the way i did using new operator.

Answer (score 1):

Write this line outside while loop. Rest seems OK.

```
         System.out.println(sb);
```